# Import android command throws error while running the command on Python shell

Tags: python

I am trying to execute "import android" command on the python shell. It gives error like this :

```
>>> **import android**  
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>  
  import android  
File ".\android.py", line 51  
  print result['error']    
             ^
```

I'm having python 3.3.2 installed on the PC (windows 7) and have android.py (SL4A) available in the python directory on my system and the system path also contains python.

Plz help in resolving this error.

Answer (score 1):

Print changed from a statement to a function on Python 3. And the module(android) you're trying to import is written for Python 2.

You should either use a Python 2 interpreter, or find(or make) that module compatible with Python 3.